# Openess of source code/drivers android phones

Tags: android, linux, drivers

How open is the source code of android phones? I cannot think of a way that manufacturers can close their drivers, because they have to conform to the GPLv2 as the License of the Linux kernel states. Or do they use write a large part in user space code, where they can choose their own licence?

The information I'm trying to get here is: How difficult is it to get a "cheap" smartphone (htc wildfire-s) and run Linux on top of it full featured. What I mean is every hardware feature is easily accesible without having to implement your own drivers and reverse engineer the device (assuming that the device is rooted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found my answer at last. A lot of firmware of a lot of android phones is delivered binary only. Which makes it less open. If I want to run GNU/Linux on top of a stock phone I run in a lot of those issues. See Richard Stallmans article on how free android is:
[Is Android really free software?](http://www.guardian.co.uk/technology/2011/sep/19/android-free-software-stallman)

There is also a project [Replicant](http://replicant.us/about/) which tries to create a free (FSF definition of free) android based stack.

Answer (score 1):

HTC has the developers area:

http://htcdev.com/devcenter

The kernel sources for the HTC wildfire you can also download there:

http://htcdev.com/devcenter/downloads

Note that not all the functionality is included in the kernel. To add functionality to your system you also have to install basic programs like a shell.

The Android system image already contains all necesary programs to run your system and som Android stuff which is not needed for a Linux-only system.

As an alternative you can have a look in the android source and remove all the unwanted programs from your custom android build.

http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html

Comment: Does this include all driver sources for enabling a functional device. Let's say "port" these drivers to _the_ linux kernel (removing wakelocks) and run a full featured device (without the android stuff)?

Comment: Yes I know I have to put a basic system on top. That system could be anything (simplest could be busybox). Most important part is that the hardware is accessible via clear APIs. What you see in some drivers is that you need some proprietary image uploaded to the driver to let the hardware become functional?